# Is anagnoristic a word? if not, is there another way to say anagnorisis in the same manner?

Tags: synonyms, rhetorical-devices

Is anagnoristic a word? especially for an formal essay.

Comment: I knew a guy (native speaker of Russian) who would often put "istic" on the end of English words.

Comment: It would be a killer Scrabble word. But, alas, it's not found in the Scrabble dictionary. :-(

Comment: If there were a verb "anagnorise" or some such, then "anagnoristic" would be a valid adjective.  But "anagnorisis" is a noun, and there is apparently no corresponding verb that is at all recognized.  Looking at the definition, it's not clear that there would be much call for a verb form.

Comment: The OED doesn't have it, either. You could probably coin it *as an adjective* and be understood, at least by folks who recognize anagnorisis. You might want to consider the form anagnoritic(al) (also not in the OED, alas) if you do want an adjective, though. Compare crisis=>critical, catharsis=>cathartic, analysis=>analytic(al), diuresis=>diuretic(al), etc.

Answer (score 1):

The correct display (for lack of a better word) of anagnoristic is Anagnorisis. Unless these two things don't mean the same thing, no, in terms of a formal essay, anagnoristic is not a word (it's not a word either way, really).
Hope this helped!